# Texturing Multiple Entities with OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android

Tags: android, entity-framework, opengl-es, textures

I need a bit of an explanation of exactly how to apply textures to different entities. My understanding is that there can only be one bound texture at a time. So, if I have many entities all using different textures how do i go about applying a texture to an entity, rendering the entity, then binding the next to apply to the next entity.

I guess I'm confused about the timing of applying a texture to an entity and rendering it with the correct texture. I am planning on using texture atlases for similar sprites and animations and stuff. But i don't know how to have a texture or a portion of a texture (texture atlas) saved to an entity before rendering so i can move on to applying the next texture to the other entities.

Similarly, if i have a texture atlas loaded and use it to animate one entity but also need a different entity to animate, that uses a different texture atlas, do i need to have the game load the other atlas and apply it to achieve the other animation?

I'm familiar with the opengl es 2.0 api. I just need help how to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are looking for a nice application structure achieve a sprite animation using atlas textures. Know there are very many good ways to do that so I will try to explain only one.

It is best to handle your situation in quite a few classes which control textures and models.

In the bottom you should create a class that handles a texture, it contains a texture ID and if it is loaded from file should contain a file name (or some custom ID). What this class should contain as public are:

- constructors as needed: with size (FBO), with name (from file)
- bind (binds the texture)
- texture size
- image size on texture (in cases when applying a non POT image to a POT texture)
- Explicit cleanup (deletes the texture)

After that since you are talking about animation it suggests you have an image with multiple subimages (a walking character for instance). That is best to subclass the texture class so it contains all the additional methods as in getting coordinates for a specific frame.

Then a level higher you would need a class that represents a texture pool. This class will cache the textures so you can reuse them. It should have an array of all the texture classes currently loaded and have methods such as:

- texture named (returns a texture with a specific name either from the cache or it creates a new texture class with this name and stores it)
- explicit cleanup (simply delete all the texture and empty the cache)

After that you generate a model class which contains all the data needed to be drawn. It either has a vertex buffer ID or can generate all the vertex data on the fly. Beside that it contains the texture(s) (link) which is grabbed from the texture pool class. At this point there are basically two ways of drawing this model. One is to do it all in your main drawing method which I discourage but is quickly to do. The other is to implement a method on a model class as in "draw with shader" to which you pass your custom shader class and the model itself contains the code to draw itself. The pipeline of which is something like:

- Bind linked texture
- Get and bind the texture coordinates from the texture (or the atlas subclass)
- Get and bind the position coordinates from the model
- Do any additional setting needed on the shader
- Draw

This way you will have an ultimate control on what is going on and you may optimize the system to a great extend. For instance when you iterate through models to be drawn you may sort them by texture so you lose unnecessary bound texture switching, you may create a large vertex buffer to flush them in a single call, you can automatically check if a specific texture is no longer needed...

Beside that this approach will have a minimum memory footprint on your application as far as the texture data goes. And as far as the models themselves go their resources are insignificantly small, for instance each of them contains some frame structure with 4 floating values and a pointer to a texture from the pool.

I hope this explanation helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much for this response. After posting my original post, I tried a method but it did not work. I was only able to draw one object at a time. Your response should send me in the right direction. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm trying to apply what you've suggested, but I'm having trouble finding out how to make the Texture class. Is there a method to get texture/image size?

Comment: This depends on what you are using. If you are using some kind of library to load the texture then you should search for those values in that library. If not and you are pushing the raw data to the GPU then those values are used in glTexImage2D and glTexSubImage2D.